# Question on the second part of the definition of sheafification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I do not understand part $(2)$ of **Proposition-Definition 1.2** on page $64$ of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

The original texts are:

*'Given a presheaf $F$ ... $F^{+}(U)$ is the set of functions $s$ from $U$ to the union $\cup F_{P}$ ... $(2)$ for each $P\in U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $P$, contained in $U$, and an element $t\in F(V)$, such that for all $Q\in V$, the germ $t_{Q}$ of $t$ at $Q$ is equal to $s(Q)$.'*

What I understand so far:

1) I know the definition of a presheaf and a sheaf.

2) I understand stalk $F_{P}$ at a point $P$ as a direct limit.

What I don't understand is specifically:

1) What does the germ $t_{Q}$ of $t$ at $Q$ mean?

$s(Q)$ is an element of stalk $F_{Q}$ which would force $t_{Q}\in F_{Q}$ but what is $t_{Q}$?

Comment: There's a map $\mathscr F(V) \to \mathscr F_Q$ by the definition of the direct limit. In Hartshorne's notation I guess $t_Q$ is $\langle V, t\rangle$.

Comment: I get some idea. You mean $t_Q$ is $f(t)\in F_{Q}$ where $t\in F(V)$ and $f:F(V)\rightarrow F_{Q}$ is the map associated with direct limit, right?

Comment: Yes. Hartshorne doesn't say much about the functorial properties of $\varinjlim$ so it's good to pick that up elsewhere.